# How to uninstall brackets from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management

I have already tried doing this:

```
sudo apt-get remove brackets
```

but I always get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "brackets", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install brackets"

E: Unable to locate package brackets
```

Comment: How about `sudo snap remove brackets` then?

Comment: or if you installed it from the Ubuntu Software Center go back into USC and uninstall from there?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from APT logs, brackets has been installed as a `snap` package.

In such case you can remove your snap package with:

```
sudo snap remove brackets
```

You can also use `Ubuntu Dock` -> [image] `Applications` -> [image] `Ubuntu Software` to remove an installed APT or snap package.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you have installed it in the first place, maybe you should try the following,

sudo snap remove cprov-brackets

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed Brackets via snap package. You can remove it form your system using the following command:

```
sudo snap install brackets --classic
```